# play run runs fine, but executing sbt directly reports missing Entry type

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a very simple Play project that uses the Jedis Redis open source library.  The library references Entry static inner class from `java.util.Map`.  The project runs perfectly when I execute `play run` but when I used `sbt` command (tried both locally and on cloudbees) :

```
sbt -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean compile test dist
```

I get the below error.

```
[error] /scratch/jenkins/workspace/fit001/app/redis/clients/util/JedisByteHashMap.java:31: not found: type Entry
[error]     public Set<Entry<byte[], byte[]>> entrySet() {
[error] 

           ^
```

`Entry` is a static inner class of `java.util.Map`. It doesn't make sense to me why it can't find the class.

Comment: Why compile Jedis yourself instead of just adding the library as a binary dependency?

Comment: Per your suggestion, I added Jedis as a library dependency and ran into class not found issue.  Any idea?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035225/sbt-compile-failed-to-see-dependent-library

Answer (score 1):

Play requires some additional setup when running from an sbt command. Check out the play script in its installation.